# Moving average/total algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, moving-average

I need to keep track of the last 7 days work hours in a flat file reading loop. It's being used to measure 'fatigueability' of work rosters.

Right now I have something that works, but it seems rather verbose and I'm not sure whether there's a pattern that's more succinct.

Currently, I have a Java class with a static array to hold the last x days data, then as I read through the file, I chop off the first element and move the other 6 (for a week rolling total) back by one. The processing of this static array is done in its own method ie.

```
/**
 * Generic rolling average/total method. Keeps adding to an array of 
 * last 'x' seen.
 * @param d Datum point you want to add/track.
 * @param i Number of rolling periods to keep track of eg. 7 = last 7 days
 *          NOT USED AT MOMENT DURING TESTING
 * @param initFlag A flag to initialize static data set back to empty.
 * @return The rolling total for i periods.
 */
private double rollingTotal(double d, boolean initFlag) {
    // Initialize running total array eg. for new Employyes
    if (initFlag) {
        runningTotal = null;
    }
    else {
        // move d+1 back to d eg. element 6 becomes element 5
        for (int x = 0; x< 6 ; x++) {
            runningTotal[x] = runningTotal[x+1];
        }
        // Put current datum point at end of array.
        runningTotal[6]= d;
    }
    // Always return sum of array when this method is called.
    double myTotal = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x<7; x++) {
        myTotal+= runningTotal[x];
    }
    System.err.print(Arrays.toString(runningTotal)+ '\n' );
    return myTotal;
}
```

My question: is this a reasonable design approach, or is there something blindingly obvious and simple to do this task?
Thanks guys

Comment: Good clear answers below: there are few 'moving average' type questions in StackOverflow, hopefully people will find this question (and its answers) to a common, generic kind of programming problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say use a queue and push the new and pop the old.  For keeping track of the average, you could also just subtract the popped value from the running total and add the new one (you'd need a static or instance variable or to pass the old sum in).  No need to access the rest of the elements.  Also, where is runningTotal being initialized if not when the initFlag is true?

```
private double rollingTotal(double d, boolean initFlag) {
    if(initFlag) vals = new Queue<Integer>();
    else {
        if(vals.size() == 7) // replace 7 with i.
            total -= vals.pop().intValue();
        }
        vals.push(d);
        total += d;
    }
    return total;
}
```

I believe Queue is abstract, so you'll need to figure out which implementation to use.  I suggest a linked-list-based one.

Comment: Thanks alot guys: I've got the message: use a higher-level object and exploit the relevant methods or a circular buffer. Great answers, all of them. When you think about it, you always need access to the entire array so you can get rid of that first entry - which I wasn't 100% sure of on my own.  I'm relieved that I hadn't missed some 1 liner and was basically on a reasonable, if not efficient and terse track! This is what I love about this site: high-quality, relevant answers from people who know their sh*t.

Comment: @Kevin: runningTotal is getting initialized in the main file processing loop as the file hits new employees.

Comment: @daniloqio : yes you're right, it needs setting and returning as zero (although the main code logic handles ie. ignore the return value in the case when the initFlag is true);

Answer (score 5):

That certainly works, but you're doing a little more work than you have to. You can avoid moving all that data around, and you can set it up so computing the next total is a matter of subtracting the oldest value, and adding the new value.

For example:

```
// assume that currentIndex is where you want to add the new item
// You have another value, currentTotal, that is initialized at 0.
currentTotal = currentTotal - runningTotal[currentIndex] + d;
runningTotal[currentIndex] = d;
// increment the index.
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % 7;
```

This uses a circular buffer and keeps the `currentTotal` so that it's always available.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using a circular buffer instead of moving all the data with every addition:

```
runningTotal[nextIndex] = d;
nextIndex+=1;
if (nextIndex>=7) nextIndex = 0;
```

So `nextIndex` is always pointing to the oldest datum.  You can still sum from the beginning to the end as before.

Comment: Another nifty one: I'm getting the message, using a circular buffer, or higher-level object gives you access to methods that simply things. Thanks JCooper.

Comment: You will have to store the nextIndex in the text file; I think this is not a better design approach, as the question asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [exponential weighted moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing).  Its rather long to write but the code is trivial by comparison.  It tends to give smoother results as well.

```
double previous;
static final double DAY = 1.0;
static final double WEEK = 6.0;
static final double ALPHA = DAY/WEEK;

private double movingAverage(double d) {
    return previous = ALPHA * d + (1 - ALPHA) * previous ;
}
```

Note: this is an optimized version of the formula

```
double previous;
static final double DAY = 1.0;
static final double WEEK = 6.0;
static final double ALPHA = 1 - Math.exp(-DAY/WEEK);

private double movingAverage(double d) {
    return previous = ALPHA * d + (1 - ALPHA) * previous ;
}
```

In this case, the later formula is more accurate and as alpha doesn't change the overhead of `Math.exp` isn't important.  If alpha can change, and is typically small, I suggest using the first formula.

Comment: Provided implementation was giving me negative results. Have used this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9201081/488489

Comment: @AndreyNovikov Apart from initializing the value to the first value instead of 0, the formula is the same.

Comment: @AndreyNovikov ... the same that is after I fixed it by changing the `-` to a `+` Thank you for picking up that it was wrong.

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out later and finished up with your corrected version. :)

Comment: @AndreyNovikov if alpha is not small, I have added a formula which is more accurate, though slower. Note: though the formula was right the name `ALPHA` was incorrect.  I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to use an ArrayList instead of an array.  Then you could just use

```
ArrayList<Double> runningTotal = new ArrayList<Double>();

....

runningTotal.remove(0);
runningTotal.add(d);
```

Comment: Nice, short neat solution Mamboking!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you initialize `runningTotal` to null? What is its type? Where it is declared? It would do well if you put some code samples that resemble actual Java code.

Moving on, my critique would be the following: your function does too much. A function, or method, should be cohesive. More appropriately, they should do one thing and one thing only.

Worse still, what happens in your for loop when x = 5? You copy `runningTotal[6]` into `runningTotal[5]`, but then you have two copies of the same value at position 5 and 6.

In your design, your function

1. moves/shuffles the items in your array
2. calculates the total
3. prints stuff to standard error
4. returns the total

It does too much.

My first suggestion is not to move stuff around in the array. Instead, implement a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) and use it instead of the array. It will simplify your design. My second suggestion is to break down things into functions that are cohesive:

1. have a data structure (a circular buffer) that allows you to add to it (and that drops the oldest entry whenever it reaches its capacity.)
2. have the data structure implement an interator
3. have a function that calculates the total on the iterator (you don't care if you are calculating the total out of an array, list or circular bufer.)
4. don't call it total. Call it sum, which is what you are computing.

That's what I'd do :)

```
// java pseudocode below - might not compile.

// assume you have a class called CircularBuffer, of say, doubles,
public class CircularBuffer
{
  public CircularBuffer(final int capacity) {...}
  public int getSize(){ ... return # of elements in it ... }
  public add(final Double d){ ... add to the end, drop from the front if we reach capacity... }
  public Iterator<Double> iterator(){ ... gets an interator over the content of the buffer ...}
}

// somewhere else, in another class... NOT ON CircularBuffer

public class Calculator
{
  //assume none of the double values is null
  static public Double sum(final Double ... doubles )
  {
    double sum= 0;
    for( Double d : doubles )
    {
      total += d.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum;
  }

 // you can calculate other things too
 static public Double avg(final Double ... doubles ){...}
 static public Double std(final Double ... doubles ){...}
}

/// somewhere else
{
  CircularBuffer buffer = new CircularBuffer(7);

  while( readingAndReadingAndReading )
  {
    // drops oldest values as it reaches capacity
    // always keeping the latest 7 readings
    buffer.add( getLatestValueFromSomewhere() );
  }

  System.out.println( "total=" + Calculator.sum() );
  System.out.println( "average=" + Calculator.avg() );
  System.out.println( "standard deviation=" + Calculator.std() );
}
```

Comment: That's great info luis, however remember this function is a small part of the functionality of the class, and it would be overkill to add too much code to make it perfect. You are technically correct, and I understand my code does 'too much' but at the same time sometimes it's better to err on the side of smaller, clearer code than go for perfection. Given my Java skills, even making the pseudocode you describe compile would have me blow my budget on this (!), but thanks for the clear description.

Comment: Hmmm, it's not about perfection, but about established industrial practices that we have know for the last 3 decades. Clean code is always one that is partitioned. We have decades of evidence that indicate this is the way to go in the general case (in terms of cost-efficiency, defect reduction, comprehension, etc)... **unless** it is throw-away code for **a one-time kind** of thing. It is never costly to do this when one starts any problem analysis in this manner. Coding 101, break down the problem and the code follows, neither overkill nor difficult ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your task is too simple and the aproach you have adopted is certainly good for the job. However, if you want to use a better design, you must get rid of all that number movement; you better use a FIFO queue and make good use of push and pop methods; that way the code wont reflect any data movement, just the two logic actions of "new data" and "remove data older than 7 days".