# Implementing exponential moving average in Java

Tags: java, math, lowpass-filter

I essentially have an array of values like this:

```
0.25, 0.24, 0.27, 0.26, 0.29, 0.34, 0.32, 0.36, 0.32, 0.28, 0.25, 0.24, 0.25
```

The above array is oversimplified, I'm collecting 1 value per millisecond in my real code and I need to process the output on an algorithm I wrote to find the closest peak before a point in time. My logic fails because in my example above, `0.36` is the real peak, but my algorithm would look backwards and see the very last number `0.25` as the peak, as there's a decrease to `0.24` before it.

The goal is to take these values and apply an algorithm to them which will "smooth" them out a bit so that I have more linear values. (ie: I'd like my results to be curvy, not jaggedy)

I've been told to apply an exponential moving average filter to my values. How can I do this? It's really hard for me to read mathematical equations, I deal much better with code.

How do I process values in my array, applying an exponential moving average calculation to even them out?

```
float[] mydata = ...
mySmoothedData = exponentialMovingAverage(mydata, 0.5);

float[] exponentialMovingAverage(float[] input, float alpha) {
    // what do I do here?
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To compute an [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average), you need to keep some state around and you need a tuning parameter. This calls for a little class (assuming you're using Java 5 or later):

```
class ExponentialMovingAverage {
    private double alpha;
    private Double oldValue;
    public ExponentialMovingAverage(double alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public double average(double value) {
        if (oldValue == null) {
            oldValue = value;
            return value;
        }
        double newValue = oldValue + alpha * (value - oldValue);
        oldValue = newValue;
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

Instantiate with the decay parameter you want (may take tuning; should be between 0 and 1) and then use `average(…)` to filter.

---

When reading a page on some mathmatical recurrence, all you really need to know when turning it into code is that mathematicians like to write indexes into arrays and sequences with subscripts. (They've a few other notations as well, which doesn't help.) However, the EMA is pretty simple as you only need to remember one old value; no complicated state arrays required.

Comment: In fact, the EMA is the _easiest_ moving average to code (provided you have somewhere to store state state like a Java object) because you don't need to do complex state management.

Comment: So I essentially just `for (float dude : input) { output[index] = ema.average(dude); }`?

Comment: @TKKocheran: Pretty much. Isn't it nice when things can be simple? (If starting with a new sequence, get a new averager.) Note that the first few terms in the averaged sequence will jump around a bit due to boundary effects, but you get those with other moving averages too. However, a _good_ advantage is that you can wrap the moving average logic into the averager and experiment without disturbing the rest of your program too much.

Answer (score 4):

I am having a hard time understanding your questions, but I will try to answer anyway.

1) If your algorithm found 0.25 instead of 0.36, then it is wrong. It is wrong because it assumes a monotonic increase or decrease (that is "always going up" or "always going down"). Unless you average ALL your data, your data points---as you present them---are nonlinear. If you really want to find the maximum value between two points in time, then slice your array from `t_min` to `t_max` and find the max of that subarray.

2) Now, the concept of "moving averages" is very simple: imagine that I have the following list: [1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5]. I can "smooth it out" by taking the average of two numbers: [1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.5]. Notice that the first number is the average of 1.5 and 1.4 (second and first numbers); the second (new list) is the average of 1.4 and 1.5 (third and second old list); the third (new list) the average of 1.5 and 1.4 (fourth and third), and so on. I could have made it "period three" or "four", or "n". Notice how the data is much smoother. A good way to "see moving averages at work" is to go to Google Finance, select a stock (try Tesla Motors; pretty volatile (TSLA)) and click on "technicals" at the bottom of the chart. Select "Moving Average" with a given period, and "Exponential moving average" to compare their differences.

Exponential moving average is just another elaboration of this, but weights the "older" data less than the "new" data; this is a way to "bias" the smoothing toward the back. Please read the Wikipedia entry.

So, this is more a comment than an answer, but the little comment box was just to tiny. Good luck.

Comment: +1: It's relatively easy to find minima and maxima, but it's much harder to work out their significance, since you need to look at deviations from long-term patterns. Under the assumption that such patterns exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/jrugged/source/browse/branches/jrugged-spring/jrugged-core/src/main/java/org/fishwife/jrugged/MovingAverage.java?spec=svn72&r=72).
If your noise has zero average, consider also the use of a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#The_Kalman_filter).

Answer (score 0):

In a rolling manner.... i also use commons.apache math library

```
  public LinkedList EMA(int dperiods, double alpha)
                throws IOException {
            String line;
            int i = 0;
            DescriptiveStatistics stats = new SynchronizedDescriptiveStatistics();
            stats.setWindowSize(dperiods);
            File f = new File("");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            LinkedList<Double> ema1 = new LinkedList<Double>();
            // Compute some statistics
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                double sum = 0;
                double den = 0;
                System.out.println("line: " + " " + line);
                stats.addValue(Double.parseDouble(line.trim()));
                i++;
                if (i > dperiods)
                    for (int j = 0; j < dperiods; j++) {
                        double var = Math.pow((1 - alpha), j);
                        den += var;
                        sum += stats.getElement(j) * var;
                        System.out.println("elements:"+stats.getElement(j));
                        System.out.println("sum:"+sum);
                    }
                else
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        double var = Math.pow((1 - alpha), j);
                        den += var;
                        sum += stats.getElement(j) * var;
                    }
                ema1.add(sum / den);
                System.out.println("EMA: " + sum / den);
            }
            return ema1;
        }
```

Comment: PLEASE USE  commons.apache math library  BEFORE GIVING A THUMBS DOWN :(

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MovingAvarage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] array = {1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5};

    double St = 0D;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        St = movingAvarage(St, array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(St);

}

private static double movingAvarage(double St, double Yt) {
    double alpha = 0.01, oneMinusAlpha = 0.99;
    if(St <= 0D) {
        St = Yt;
    } else {
        St = alpha*Yt + oneMinusAlpha*St;
    }
    return St;
   }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -5):

If you're having trouble with the math, you could go with a simple moving average instead of exponential.  So the output you get would be the last x terms divided by x.  Untested pseudocode:

```
int data[] = getFilled();
int outdata[] = initializeme()
for (int y = 0; y < data.length; y++)
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = y; x < y-5; x++)
        sum+=data[x];
    outdata[y] = sum / 5;
```

Note that you will need to handle the start and end parts of the data since clearly you can't average the last 5 terms when you are on your 2nd data point.  Also, there are more efficient ways of calculating this moving average(sum = sum - oldest + newest), but this is to get the concept of what's happening across.