# JAVA : Low-pass filter

Tags: java, android, lowpass-filter

I'm a french student and actually I realize an internship in Mobile Application.

I created an application to have information about accelerometer sensor with this code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accelerometer);
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    acceleration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.acceleration);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    acceleration.setText("X: "+event.values[0]+
            "\nY: "+event.values[1]+
            "\nZ: "+event.values[2]);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
```

}

But now I want to implement a low-pass filter to smooth data but I don't know how can I do this ?

So, If someone can help me about this problem

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: I'm sorry about that I'm new in programming. It's more about JAVA Script so ?

Comment: No problem. The post has been edited accordingly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an [exponential moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average). It'll act as a low pass filter and is [trivial to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201081/3199595)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm a debutant in programming so I don't have lot of knowledge. Can you help me ?